axiomatic set theory basic question
Given two classes $x$ and $y$, does this statement hold $x \in y \lor x \not \in y$? I know that if $x$ is a proper class, then it should hold since $x$ is a proper class if and only for every class $z$, then $x \not \in z$. However, if $x$ is a set, then intuitively it seems that this statement will hold, but I know that in mathematics there are some statements that cannot be proved using the current axioms. Sorry I am not too acquainted with ZFC or NBG.

Define $P(x,y) ::= x \in y$ : how could  $P(x,y) \lor \lnot P(x,y)$ not hold?

In ZFC the domain of discourse includes only sets, not proper classes.

Fuzzy set theory, @FrançoisJurain.

@Shaun 1st time I see ${}\in{}$ interpreted as the fuzzy membership function.

@All I fail to see any connection whatsoever between the question and ${}\in{}$, indeed with set theory.

The Law of Excluded Middle: In predicate logic (and others), $\Psi \lor \lnot \Psi$ for all statements $\Psi$.
$x\in y$ is a statement in the language of ZFC, and ZFC is a theory in predicate logic. Therefore $(x\in y)\lor \lnot (x\in y)$.

@WillFitchet yeah this makes sense.

I have made my comment into an answer since the OP seemed happy with it.
The Law of Excluded Middle: In classical predicate logic (and some other types of logic), $\Psi \lor \lnot \Psi$ for all statements $\Psi$.
$x\in y$ is a statement in the language of ZFC, and ZFC is a theory in predicate logic. Therefore $(x\in y)\lor \lnot (x\in y)$.
The intuitionist school of logic holds the following position:

"If we know that it is not the case that a statement $\Psi$ is provably false, we don't necessarily know that $\Psi$ is provably true either."

It follows that in intuitionist logic we cannot use the law of excluded middle to prove statements.

Suppose there are sets $x,y$ such that neither $y\not\in x$ nor $y\in x$. So $\exists x\exists y\neg(y\in x\lor y\not\in x)$. Well then by De Morgan $\neg(y\in x\lor y\not\in x)\leftrightarrow (y\not\in x\land y\in x)$ and so $\exists x\exists y(y\in x\land y\not\in x)$, which is a contradiction.
There is a similar statement to this, namely $\exists x\forall y\neg(y\in x\lor y\not\in x)$.  Then again by De Morgan $\exists x\forall y(y\not\in x\land y\in x)$. But $\forall y(y\not\in x)$ means $x$ is empty; on the other hand $\forall y(y\in x)$ means $x$ is the class of all sets. Hence if the statement holds, the universe $x$ must be empty, so there are no sets. Depending in which way you postulate ZF, this either contradicts set existence or infinity.
